# WordPress Timber getting posts of a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I'm just digging into WordPress plus Timber and I came upon a problem that I can't resolve.

I have created a custom post type called "project", within which I created a custom field called "project_category". That custom field contains a checkbox of two choices (graphic, web design).

The question is what can I do to display all the projects that contains the project_category "graphic"?

Here is how I started:

**graphic.php template**

I created a graphic.php file with those wp queries:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();

$args = array(
    // Get post type project
    'post_type' => 'project',
    // Get all posts
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    // Gest post by "graphic" category
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'project_category',
            'value' => 'graphic',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    // Order by post date
    'orderby' => array(
        'date' => 'DESC'
    ),
);

$posts = Timber::get_posts( $args );
$context['graphic'] = Timber::get_posts('$args');

Timber::render( 'graphic.twig', $context );
```

**graphic.twig**
Then I create a twig file with this loop.

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="l-container">

    <main role="main">
        <div class="l-row">
            <h1>My graphic design projects</h1>

            {% for post in posts %}

                <a href="{{ post.link }}" class="project-images l-col l-col--1-of-4 l-col--m-1-of-2">
                    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>

                        {% if post.thumbnail %}
                            <img src="{{post.get_thumbnail.src('medium_large')}}" alt="{{post.title}}" />
                        {% endif %}
                </a>

            {% endfor %}
        </div> 
    </main>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

With this solution I can get only one project. When I want to display more than one project the project doesn't show up.
I tried to use "for post in projects" or "for post in post.projects", but nothing worked out really.

What can I do to display all the projects that contains the project_category "graphic"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

@filnug, you're almost there. I think there's just some confusion about sending vars from PHP to Twig:

## graphic.php:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$args = array(
// Get post type project
'post_type' => 'project',
// Get all posts
'posts_per_page' => -1,
// Gest post by "graphic" category
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'project_category',
        'value' => 'graphic',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
),
// Order by post date
'orderby' => array(
    'date' => 'DESC'
));

$context['graphics'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );
```

### twig file:

```
{% for post in graphics %}
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    (other markup goes here)

{% endfor %}
```

best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a million Jared.
I'am a bit late to answer you, but you're comment helped me a lot. 

I just had to add the render of my twig template (Timber::render( 'graphic.twig', $context );) at the end of the wp query in "graphic.php".